# "Name of the transition routes should be unique." error while saving route groups

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I see the "Name of the transition routes should be unique." error while saving route groups in Dialogflow CX. I can't add or remove any routes to the route group, nor can I modify any particular route.

How do I debug or fix the issue given I'm stuck and can't make any changes? I don't have any two transition groups with the same names.

Comment: Hi @Hasit Bhatt, Could you try exporting your Agent as a JSON file and check if there are any duplicate entries in the agent ?

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.